# xterm color theme in Linux terminal style

Tags: xterm

In case of using command to launch xterm windows, the options I have so far is `xterm -fn 8x16 -geometry 100x30`. It's with white background and black font color. I was wondering if it's possible to have Linux Konsole/Terminal style color theme (black background, white font color, `ls` with colored result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm)

Specifically you want the `-bg` and `-fg` parameters, and probably a few others that you'll find in [the man page for `xterm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm).
You can also set these values via [the .Xresources file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources) so you don't have to pass them as command-line arguments every time.